# I run thonny and have no module name RPI error

Tags: rpi.gpio

I run Thonny on a pi zero.(i am a beginner)
want to activate gpio
i get an error" import rpi.gpio as pigo, modulenotfounderror: no module name 'rpi'.
i have update library. still not working.

Comment: `import RPi.GPIO as pigo` - remember Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Python is case sensitive, use:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```